# Application of Central Limit Theorem where $n=39$ only.

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

**I have been solving the following exercise:**

Lets say we have a chip with a critical component that needs to be replaced from time to time as soon as it breaks. Lets say that such a component is expected to break after 30 days. Now lets say we have an infinite amount of replacement parts, then the random variables
$$
T_i\stackrel{iid}{\sim} Exp(\lambda=\tfrac{1}{30})\quad\text{for }i\in\{1,2,...\}
$$
denote the lifetime of the $i$-th component. Now let
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^{39} T_i
$$
be the time until we have replaced the component 38 times. What is the probability, that we will do more than 38 replacements within three years?

**My textbook suggests the following solution:**

In other words, we're looking for the probability $Pr[S<3\cdot365]=Pr[S<1095]$.

We know that
$$
E[S]=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{39}T_i\right]
=\sum_{i=1}^{39}E[T_i]=39\cdot E[T_1] = 39\cdot 30 = 1170.
$$
$$
Var[S]=Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^{39}T_i\right]
=\sum_{i=1}^{39}Var[T_i]
=39\cdot Var[T_1]=39\cdot 30^2=35100.
$$
Now due to the central limit theorem we know that:
$$
P[S<1095]=P\left[\frac{S-E[S]}{\sqrt{Var[S]}} <\frac{1095-E[S]}{\sqrt{Var[S]}}\right]\approx\Phi(-0.4)=1-\Phi(0.4)\approx 0.3346.
$$

**What I can't understand about the solution:**

I know what the central limit theorem is about: In this case, $T_1,T_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with $Exp(\lambda)$ with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Now let $S_n$ denote
$$
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_i
$$
Therefore $S_n$ has the expected value $n\mu$ and Variance $n\sigma^2$. So in this case with the central limit theorem we have:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left[\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\leq z\right] = \Phi(z).
$$
Which iswhat we have in the last line of the solution - except for the limit.

Now in this exercise we're not really taking the limit of $n$. Instead $n$ is just 39. Is the solution of the textbook just an approximation? If so, what are the reasons that one can take this approximation, even if $n$ is not going to infinity? Is this the best we can approximate the desired probability with? Or is the infinite sampling happening elsewhere, which would give us a valid reason to use the theorem?

Comment: The solution of the textbook is just an approximation. Here, $39$ is big enough that the approximation is a very good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions in order...

1. Yes, the solution in your textbook is an approximation.
2. You rely on the Central Limit Theorem to make this approximation.
3. I would argue that, by and large, this *is* the best you can approximate the desired probability without using brute force methods where you are required to use a calculator to calculate this directly.
4. The infinite sampling isn't happening, per se.  The Central Limit Theorem states that the sample mean ($\bar{X}=\frac{S_n}{n}$) of a population is Normally distributed, regardless of the distribution of the original variable ($X$), **provided that $n$ is large enough.**  One can prove that, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the sample mean of ($\bar{X}$) will become more and more Normally distributed such that if it were possible to "plug $\infty$ in for $n$," the sample mean would be exactly Normally distributed.  What we see in practice, however, is that the sampling distribution of your sample mean will be close enough to a Normal distribution if $n$ is large enough.  Practically, most people use $n\approx 30$ as a threshold where $n$ is large enough to apply the Central Limit Theorem. One point is that I use $\bar{X}$, the sample mean, instead of $S_n$ like you use above.  The $\bar{X}$ form is the most common form of the Central Limit Theorem.  If you take each term in $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}$ and divide it by $n$, you will get $\frac{S_n/n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$.  The explanations are equivalent.